# Powershell DSC ScheduledTask: Run as group

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

In the Windows 10 Task Scheduler UI one can configure a task to run using a specific user account or a group (like BUILTIN\Users). Is there any way to specify the group BUILTIN\Users or BUILTIN\Administrators using PowerShell DSC (Desired State Configuration) for [Scheduled Tasks](https://github.com/dsccommunity/ComputerManagementDsc/wiki/ScheduledTask)? The only options I found were BuiltInAccount (where only 3 built in accounts like LOCAL SERVICE are allowed), ExecuteAsCredential (where I can specify a user), and ExecuteAsGMSA (domain accounts only?). The reason is that I want the task to run for several users at startup, showing a UI, and do not want to configure it for all users individually.

Comment: Use `Get-DscResource ScheduledTask -syntax` to see what you can set for this DSC Resource. Then you'll have to try, or look for a different DSC Resource

Comment: @SimonS thanks, I was already at the trial and error step of your recipe (without success), and was just hoping someone else solved the problem by trying more cases.